# What is the best way to determine server resources each remote user is using

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, monitoring

I manage some Win2008R2 servers on the network for my department. Each server usually has 10 - 20 users at a time connected to it. They are nothing more than locked down file servers on the domain.

Even though they are beefy servers sometimes a user will do something which slams the IO on the server or the processor (such as copy a file over  that is several GB and psexec command line unzip it).

While I do not have a choice per my boss to further restrict rights, I do need to monitor & report it when people abuse the servers like this and have leeway to boot their sessions.

Currently I keep the Computer management console remotely connected to the servers and page through them about once every 15 min on the session tabs to see if anyone has a ton of files open, but that doesn't help determine when someone is spiking the processor. I know about that Resource monitor, but it doesn't tell me who is spiking IO/Processor.

Can someone provide a built in / easy method to be able to determine from am MMC who's sessions are causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would think of two built-in tools like

- Performance Monitor (where you can set a variety of performance counters to monitor every possible parameter to find out the root-cause of the performance issue, but unfortunately, you cannot see CPU/RAM/IO usage per User).
- Windows System Resource Manager, can be installed from Features (this one seems to be more useful in your case. It allows to allocate processor and memory resources to applications, users, Remote Desktop Services sessions. You can configure resource usage like CPU on a per user, per session, per process basis, thus eliminating the issue when somebody uses more resources than required. You can configure different schedules for different resource-set using different policices).

[Introduction to Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/03/31/two-minute-drill-introduction-to-windows-system-resource-manager-wsrm.aspx)

[Using Windows System Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754150.aspx)

Hope this helps.